# Working with lists (Python) some easy questions

Tags: python-2.7

This question is a bit tricky, at least for me. I want to get all the names in a text. Easy, or? ;-)

Let’s start with a simple code:

```
    for m in re.finditer("(?:Dr\.|med\.|Family)\s*([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)?)", my_text):
    print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(1))
```

Now I get names with their index like:

```
    74090-74112: Johannes Restnoan ###this should be two seperate names on the new list
    87125-87138: Matheus
```

Now I want to put all that names found, on a list and check the list with my_text and create a new list, like:

```
    namecheck = set(that_list_i_created).intersection(my_text)
```

This is somehow possible, or? How do i create that list (Johannes, Restnoan, Matheus) with the names?

And is it possible to get the index of the words on that last list?

Comment: Just add m.group(1) to a new list, and split it on a space to add each name separately

Comment: I tried this earlier today, but i only get "113782-113795: Johannes".

Comment: Show what you tried, because it's not what I suggested

Answer (score 0):

I got it done:

```
    list=[]
```

and thn:

```
    list.append((m.start(), m.end(), m.group(1)))
```